# audio played exceeds the set duration in java

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I am taking as input a text message from the user. According to the alphabets in the text message, I am maintaining an array (named as duration in the code) which stores the time for which audio1 has to be played.

I am alternatively playing two audio files in the loop at the specific positions and stopping them as well.

first audio file is played till the duration of first letter and then the second audio file is set with position value with the duration value and played till duration + 2 sec . everytime the value is incremented appropriately.

But when I play it sometimes stop at the correct position (like for first two iterations) but sometimes it exceeds the set position and starts playing audio file completely till end.

why is this happening?

I am using eclipse to write and run java code.

My java code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.*; 
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineListener;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

public class Stegano implements LineListener{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    static long[] duration;
    static boolean playCompleted1;
    static boolean playCompleted2;
    static int ch;
    static float rate,r;

    //public static AudioFormat.Encoding PCM_SIGNED;
    public static AudioFormat getOutFormat(AudioFormat inFormat){
        ch = inFormat.getChannels();
        rate = inFormat.getSampleRate();
        r = rate;
    //  convertToFrames();
        return new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED ,7200,16,ch,ch*2,rate,inFormat.isBigEndian());
    }
    /*public static void convertToFrames(){
        int i ;
        for(i=0;i<duration.length;i++){
            duration[i] = (r*duration[i])/1000;
            System.out.println(duration[i]);
        }
    }*/
    void convertToAudio(){
        final File file1 = new File("E:/Jeena_Jeena_wapking.wav");
        final File file2 = new File("E:/Jeena_Jeena_wapking.wav");

        try {
            AudioInputStream in1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file1);
            AudioInputStream in2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file2);

            AudioFormat inForm1 = getOutFormat(in1.getFormat());
            AudioFormat inForm2 = getOutFormat(in2.getFormat());

            DataLine.Info info1 = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class,inForm1);
            DataLine.Info info2 = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class,inForm2);

            Clip clip1 = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(info1);
            Clip clip2 = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(info2);

            long d = 0;
            int i;
            long dt = clip1.getMicrosecondLength();
            System.out.println("Duration : " + (float)((dt / 1000000)/60.0) + "min");
            for(i=0;i< duration.length;i++){

                    System.out.println("i" + i);
                    in1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file1);
                    inForm1 = getOutFormat(in1.getFormat());
                    info1 = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class,inForm1);
                    clip1 = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(info1);
                    clip1.addLineListener(this);
                    clip1.open(in1);
                    clip1.setMicrosecondPosition(d);

                    long pos = 0; 
                    clip1.start();


                    while(true){
                        pos = clip1.getMicrosecondPosition();
                        System.out.println("pos 1: " + pos);
                        if( pos == (d + duration[i])){
                            System.out.println("posFinal : " + pos);

                            clip1.stop();
                            break;
                        }   
                    }
                    while (!playCompleted1) {
                        // wait for the playback completes
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    clip1.close();
                    playCompleted1 = false;
                    System.out.println("PLayback1 completed");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(8000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    d = d+pos;

                    in2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file2);
                    inForm2 = in2.getFormat();
                    info2 = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class,inForm2);
                    clip2 = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(info2);
                    clip2.addLineListener(this);
                    clip2.open(in2);
                    clip2.setMicrosecondPosition(d);

                    d = d+2000000;
                    //pos = 0;
                    clip2.start();

                    while(true){
                        pos = clip2.getMicrosecondPosition();
                        System.out.println("pos 2: " + pos);
                        if( pos == d){
                            System.out.println("posFinal : " + pos);

                            clip2.stop();
                            break;
                        }   
                    }
                    while (!playCompleted1) {
                        // wait for the playback completes
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    clip2.close();
                    System.out.println("PLayback2 completed");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(8000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //d = pos + 2000000;
                    playCompleted1 = false;
                  //  playCompleted2 = false;
            }


        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
            System.out.println("Audio line for playing back is unavailable.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    public void update(LineEvent event) {
        LineEvent.Type type = event.getType();

        if (type == LineEvent.Type.START) {
            System.out.println("Playback started.");

        } else if (type == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
            playCompleted1 = true;
            System.out.println("Playback completed.");
           /* if(playCompleted1 == true){
                playCompleted2 = true;
                System.out.println("Playback2 completed.");
            }*/
        }

    }
    public static void convertMsgToAudio(String msg){

        int len = msg.length();
        duration = new long[len];
        msg = msg.toUpperCase();
        System.out.println("Msg 2 : " + msg);

        int i;
        //char ch;
        for(i=0;i<msg.length();i++){

            if(msg.charAt(i) == 'A'){
                duration[i] = 500000;
            }
            else if (msg.charAt(i) == 'B'){
                duration[i] = 510000;
            }
            else if (msg.charAt(i) == 'C'){
                duration[i] = 520000;
            }
            else if (msg.charAt(i) == 'D'){
                duration[i] = 530000;               
            }
            else if (msg.charAt(i) == 'E'){
                duration[i] = 540000;
            }
            else if (msg.charAt(i) == 'F'){
                duration[i] = 550000;
            }
            else if (msg.charAt(i) == 'G'){
                duration[i] = 560000;
            }
            else if (msg.charAt(i) == 'H'){
                duration[i] = 570000;
            }
            else if (msg.charAt(i) == 'I'){
                duration[i] = 580000;
            }
            else if (msg.charAt(i) == 'J'){
                duration[i] = 600000;
            }
            else if (msg.charAt(i) == 'K'){
                duration[i] = 650000;
            }
            else if (msg.charAt(i) == 'L'){
                duration[i] = 660000;
            }
            else if (msg.charAt(i) == 'M'){
                duration[i] = 680000;
            }
            else if (msg.charAt(i) == 'N'){
                duration[i] = 700000;
            }
            else if (msg.charAt(i) == 'O'){
                duration[i] = 750000;
            }
            else if (msg.charAt(i) == 'P'){
                duration[i] = 800000;
            }
            else if (msg.charAt(i) == 'Q'){
                duration[i] = 850000;
            }
            else if (msg.charAt(i) == 'R'){
                duration[i] = 900000;
            }
            else if (msg.charAt(i) == 'S'){
                duration[i] = 950000;
            }
            else if (msg.charAt(i) == 'T'){
                duration[i] = 9800000;
            }
            else if (msg.charAt(i) == 'U'){
                duration[i] = 970000;
            }
            else if (msg.charAt(i) == 'V'){
                duration[i] = 1200000;
            }
            else if (msg.charAt(i) == 'W'){
                duration[i] = 1300000;
            }
            else if (msg.charAt(i) == 'X'){
                duration[i] = 1400000;
            }
            else if (msg.charAt(i) == 'Y'){
                duration[i] = 960000;
            }
            else if (msg.charAt(i) == 'Z'){
                duration[i] = 1600000;
            }
            else if (msg.charAt(i) == ' '){
                duration[i] = 1000000;
            }   
        }
        /*for(i=0;i<duration.length;i++){
            System.out.println(duration[i]);
        }*/
        Stegano s = new Stegano();
        s.convertToAudio();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String msg;
        System.out.print("Enter message: ");
        msg = s.nextLine();
        s.close();
        System.out.println("Msg " + msg);
        convertMsgToAudio(msg);
    }

}
```

Please help. I am new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this doing what you want?

```
pos = clip1.getMicrosecondPosition();
System.out.println("pos 1: " + pos);
if( pos == (d + duration[i])){
    System.out.println("posFinal : " + pos);
    clip1.stop();
    break;
}
```

When you check `pos == (d + duration[i])`, you're assuming that `clip1.getMicrosecondPosition()` will always be incremented by 1. If it ever increments by more than 1 it may skip the check and never terminate the loop. Try changing that line to

```
if( pos >= (d + duration[i])){
```

Same goes for the check for `clip2` further down.